# how to format label of Y-axis for categorical charts(Kendo-Chart) in Angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo-chart for showing data in Bar, line and Pie charts.

But after trying for hours I am not able to figure out how to format y-axis labels for categorical charts.

I tried using   and tried setting format as : `<kendo-chart-y-axis-item type="numeric" [labels]='{format:"{0:N2}"}'>`

But it is not affecting the y-axis labels in any way.(I assume we cannot use Scatter Chart tags for Categorical charts, right?)

Please help me in setting the required format for the labels of y axis.

is my code:

```
<kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="chart.Data.labels"
                                [labels]="{ rotation: 'auto' }"
                                [title]="chart.Options.XTitle">

</kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
```

```
<kendo-chart-value-axis-item [title]="chart.Options.YTitle">

</kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
```

```
<span *ngFor="let dataset of chart.Data.datasets">

    <kendo-chart-series-item [name]="dataset.label" [data]="dataset.data"
                             [type]="dataset.type">

        <kendo-chart-series-item-labels visible="true" [content]="setLabelFormat">

        </kendo-chart-series-item-labels> 

    </kendo-chart-series-item>

</span>
```

**Thanks in Advance....**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
<kendo-chart-value-axis>
    <kendo-chart-value-axis-item >
        <kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels [content]="functionReturningString">
        </kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels>
    </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
</kendo-chart-value-axis>
```

Comment: @lohiarahul, can you please provide sample functionReturningString() ?